# What is it called when some intentionally takes property but intends to return it

Tags: texas, theft

I placed my ~$600 phone down to go through security, and a school offical picked it up and declared that it would be returned 2 days later. I immediately requested my phone back to no avail.

I did some research and concluded that it is not legally considered stealing because the person intended to return it eventually. However, I do not know what the actual crime is or what legal options I have.

The entire student body entered through the same door but only a bag full (1/5) of phones were stolen. I find it quite irritating because there is a significant amount of personal information on such a device along with the fact that someone boldly walked away with my property.

I got my phone back, but I'm curious about what the technical term for the crime is and any legal options I have.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Trespass to chattels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass_to_chattels)?

Comment: Note that if you are a minor and a student at the school, everything is different; the school officials may be [in loco parentis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_loco_parentis).

Comment: @NateEldredge I was 18 at the time and not on school grounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a school offical picked it up and declared that it would be returned 2 days later.

Temporary or not, this can larceny. There's a huge body of case law dealing with that sort of situation. I can't readily imagine why would a school official take a phone for two days so let me quote:

> for larceny, one must intend to deprive the owner of the possession of his property either permanently **or for an unreasonable length of time**, or intend to use it in such a way that the owner will probably be thus deprived of his property."

From http://caselaw.findlaw.com/ca-supreme-court/1196383.html quoting LaFave and Scott, Substantive Criminal Law (1986) Crimes Relating to Property, § 8.5, p. 357.

Comment: So what are my options?